# How to stream live video from one PC to an Apache server on a second PC

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server, streaming, lamp

So I'm new to Apache servers and LAMP stacks in general.

I'm working on a home website that's gonna show room temperatures and a few other functions using a MySQL server.

I have a Raspberry Pi with a USB camera at my front door and I want to stream it to my Apache server to display the camera's live feed on my website. The PC is running Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Install mjpg-streamer on the Raspberry Pi

Install git: `sudo apt-get install git`

Clone mjpg-streamer-experimental: `git clone https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer/tree/master/mjpg-streamer-experimental` - The experimental version worked way better for me on my Raspberry Pi than the regular one, that's why I recommend using it.

Compile it: `cd mjpg-streamer-experimental && ./config && make`

Create a script that will start the streaming automatically on every boot: `nano onboot.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/mjpg-streamer-experimental
./mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -t pal -r 720x576" -o "output_http.so -w ./www -p 8740"
```

Replace `video0` with your video interface, `pal` with `ntsc` if your camera uses `ntsc` and `720x576` with the resolution of your camera. Then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file.

You can now run `bash ./onboot.sh` to test if the streaming works.

We will now use `cron` (should be pre-installed) to make this script run everytime on boot:

Run `crontab -e` to edit the current user's crontab and append the following line into it:

```
@reboot bash /path/to/mjpg-streamer-experimental/onboot.sh
```

Again <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file and apply it.

## 2. On your apache webserver

Now this is very simple. You are able to access mjpg-streamer's interface using `http://<your-raspberry-pi-IP>:8740` on any machine in the network. In order to embed the live scream into your website, simple put the following code on the site where you want the stream to be:

```html
<img src="http://<raspberry-pi-IP>:8740/?action=stream" />
```

Comment: It took me a while to get this to work (most issues were caused by the wrong mjpg-streamer version for me) so I'm glad I can make it easier for others! I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer as accepted if it helped you. :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. How do I do that. EDIT: Never mind I found it xD